# Optimizing total number of cables

Tags: matlab, vba, optimization

I need lots of cables of different small sizes (under 100 meters) and cables are only sold in lenghts of 100 meters.

So, to optimize my purchase, I would like a code where I can input the lengths of all pieces of cables that I need. The code will combine my inputs under the constraint the sum is under 100, while minimizing the total number of 100m-length cables that I need to buy.

If anyone could help with a code in VBA, Matlab or Python I would be very grateful.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I first thought the same. But this approach does not work because cables can only be cut, not attached. Thus, by making a sum of all small cable pieces and dividing by100, the constraint "sum of pieces < 100" will not be respected.

Comment: This definitely seems like a covering - packing problem which should be solvable by `inlinprog` or 'linprog` in MATLAB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as a [bin-packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), and it's actually very difficult (computationally speaking) to find the optimal solution.

However, it is a problem that is practically useful to solve (as you have seen for yourself) and so there are several approaches that seek to find an approximate solution--one that is "good enough" without guaranteeing that it's the best possible solution. I did a quick search and found [this course website](http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece556/matlab/), which has some examples that may help you out.

If you are looking for an exact solution, you can ask the related question "will I be able to fit the cables I need into `N` 100-meter cables?". This feasibility problem can be expressed as a "binary program", which is a special case of a "mixed-integer linear program", for which MATLAB has a solver called `intlinprog` (requires the optimization toolbox).

I'm sorry that I don't have any code to solve your problem, but I hope that this at least gives you some keywords to help you find more resources!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is like the [cutting stock problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem). There are some very good methods to solve this. [Here](http://www.amsterdamoptimization.com/pdf/colgen.pdf) is an implementation and some background. It is not too difficult to write an Excel front-end for this (see [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2009/09/vstosolver-foundation.html)).

[image]
[image]

If you google for "cutting stock problem" you will find lots of references.